# multiple join on the same table on different columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to build the SQL logic of the following scenario:

I have table called: Products which has (Item_Id, Product_Holder, Price, Month)
and another table Sales:( Item_Id, Issued_from, Sent_to, Impact_Value, Month)

If say we have a record in Products like the following:

```
Item_id | Product_Holder | Price  | Month
x       |  B123          |   10   |   2
x       |  Z555          |   8    |   3
y       |  A444          |   15   |   2
y       |  K000          |   10   |   3
```

and

```
Item_id | Issued_from    | Sent_to| Impact_Value | Month | 
x           B123            Z555                   3         
y           A444            K000                   3
```

The columns: Product_Holder, Issued_from, Sent_to  have the same type of values so you can join on those.

I tried joining on the **Item_id, Month, and Product_Holder** with **Item_id, Month, and Issued_from** and then another similar join for **Sent_to**. But it doesn't make sense to me how the those values should be calculated in order to populate **Impact_Value** column with -2, and -5 respectively.

So a sale from B123 to Z555 resulted in a -2
And a sale from A444 to K000 resulted in -5

**EDIT:**

This is not about accessing the previous row. An Item can belong to many Product_Holders with different Price for each. In the Sales table the Impact_Value will change as an item is transferred from on Product_Holder( Issue_from) to another Product_Holder(Sent_to). I want to calculate this value in the Impact_Value column.

Comment: Do those combinations always come in pairs? What if there is another row for item_id `y` with month=4?

Comment: yes Damine, you are right!

Comment: Yes a_hourse_with_no_name you can have that as well!

Comment: So what is the expected output _then_? Another row for item_id `y` or another column `further_sent_to`?

Comment: Where is your Primary?

Comment: Item_id is Primary key but we need to join on Product Holder with both Issue_from and Sent_to to do that calulcations

Comment: If you can have multiple `product_holders` for the same `item_id` in the `products` table (possibly with multiple `month` values) then I don't see how you can reliably match the rows in `sales` to the rows in `products`. You either get more than one match (when leaving out the `month` in the join) or you get no rows when including the month, as there is no `B123,3` combination in the `products` table.

Answer (score 0):

Based entirely on the data you've provided, here is one way of doing it:

```
with products as (select 'x' Item_id, 'B123' Product_Holder, 10 Price, 2 Mnth from dual union all
                  select 'x' Item_id, 'Z555' Product_Holder, 8 Price, 3 Mnth from dual union all
                  select 'y' Item_id, 'A444' Product_Holder, 15 Price, 2 Mnth from dual union all
                  select 'y' Item_id, 'K000' Product_Holder, 10 Price, 3 Mnth from dual),
        sales as (select 'x' item_id, 'B123' issued_from, 'Z555' sent_to, null impact_value, 3 mnth from dual union all
                  select 'y' item_id, 'A444' issued_from, 'K000' sent_to, null impact_value, 3 mnth from dual)
select sls.item_id,
       sls.issued_from,
       sls.sent_to,
       sum(case when prd.product_holder = issued_from then -1 * prd.price
                else prd.price
           end) impact_value,
       sls.mnth
from   products prd
       inner join sales sls on (prd.item_id = sls.item_id
                                and (prd.product_holder = sls.issued_from
                                     or (prd.product_holder = sls.sent_to
                                         and prd.mnth = sls.mnth)))
group by sls.item_id,
         sls.issued_from,
         sls.sent_to,
         sls.mnth;

ITEM_ID ISSUED_FROM SENT_TO IMPACT_VALUE       MNTH
------- ----------- ------- ------------ ----------
y       A444        K000              -5          3
x       B123        Z555              -2          3
```

And to update the sales table, I'd do:

```
merge into sales tgt
using (select sls.item_id,
              sls.issued_from,
              sls.sent_to,
              sum(case when prd.product_holder = issued_from then -1 * prd.price
                       else prd.price
                  end) impact_value,
              sls.mnth
       from   products prd
              inner join sales sls on (prd.item_id = sls.item_id
                                       and (prd.product_holder = sls.issued_from
                                            or (prd.product_holder = sls.sent_to
                                                and prd.mnth = sls.mnth)))
       group by sls.item_id,
                sls.issued_from,
                sls.sent_to,
                sls.mnth) src
  on (tgt.item_id = src.item_id
      and tgt.issued_from = src.issued_from
      and tgt.sent_to = src.sent_to
      and tgt.mnth = src.month) -- assuming these columns are enough to define a unique row in the sales table
when matched then
update set tgt.impact_value = src.impact_value;
```

N.B. You might need to work out the latest issued_from row that's at or prior to the month specified in the sales table, but that's an exercise left up to you.

I would also hope that in your real tables, you have a better identifier for the date of sale rather than just a month number. Eg. month and year, or even better, the actual date!